# Convert "FFFF" To byte

Tags: java, byte

I have a java String, and I have to convert it into byte, but the problem is byte doesn't allow this because of its range. What should I do. ?

```
String num = "FFFF";
```

Comment: Well obviously you can't. Explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have an array of Byte, and I have to put this String into that array.

Comment: Are you decoding the String (bytes represent charset) or the value it represents?

Comment: Well, a byte is 8 bits, which means its values run from 0 to 255. There's no way you can fit 0xFFFF (65535) in that range. Are you trying to convert this into an array of bytes where every character-pair from `num` is interpreted as an octet? Or are you interpreting it as a character code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte has 8bits thus values ranges from <-128,127> or <0x00,0xFF> so you can not encode 0xFFFF if it is representing integer (65535) into byte cos it would not fit.

However if it is representing Short 0xFFFF means -1 (if signed) which is convertible into byte. The code would look like this:

```
String num = "FFFF";
int n = Integer.parseInt(num,16);
System.out.println("int:"+n);
byte bn = (byte)n;
System.out.println("byte: "+bn);
```

and it would print like this:

```
int:65535
byte: -1
```